# View to filter a list of nodes which has TWO taxonomy terms

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have a content type - 'video post'.
This content type has several taxonomy terms associated with it, 'star rating' and 'warm up'.

The 'star rating' taxonomy is a list of numbers: 1, 2, 3, 4

The 'warm up' taxonomy has 3 options: warm up, long, cool down.

What I've been trying to do is to create a view block to display on the content type 'video post' so that it displays a list of nodes which have the exact same set of taxonomy terms as the one currently being viewed.

So if I go to node/1 and this has these two taxonomies as follows:

star rating - 2

warm up - long

I only want nodes to display which also have this same combination of terms.

It would also be great if I could exclude the current node from the list too, as this is obviously not required.

I've tried just about everything that I know, but I always seem to get results that I don't want.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Download the [Views PHP module:](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php)

> This module allows the admin account (user 1) to add fields, filters
>   and sorts to views which use PHP code. It also supports additional
>   accounts when the core PHP Filter module is enabled.

In Views:

- create a new View of 'video post' content type, as a block and set it up to show all entries for now, in the format and layout you desire
- add a contextual filter for the star rating field (you will need to adjust the field names appropriately):

  - Provide a default value, PHP code:

    ```
    $node = menu_get_object();
    return $node->field_star_rating['und'][0]['tid'];
    ```
- add another contextual filter for the warm up field:

  - Provide a default value, PHP code:

    ```
    $node = menu_get_object();
    return $node->field_warm_up['und'][0]['tid'];
    ```

The first line retrieves the page object (which should only ever be a video post node if the block is set up properly), then returns the term ID associated to the current node as a contextual filter to the view. This assumes a single language site.

- add a regular filter, Global PHP code:

  ```
  $node = menu_get_object();
  if($data->nid == $node->nid) return true;
  else return false;
  ```

The first line again retrieves the page object, and compares its node ID with the node ID of the current entry, filtering it if they match. It may appear backwards, but that's how the Global PHP works for some reason. Returning true excludes the row.

- under `admin/structure/block`, set the view-block to show where you want on the page, restrict it to show only on the content type video post.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. Is the 1st item: Content: Stars rating (field_stars_rating) in contextual filters and what do I choose for the regular Global filter - I don't know where to find that one?

Comment: if that is what your field is called yes - without knowing the machine names you used, I guessed.  Global PHP is the regular filter

Comment: I should be more clear - using the GUI of views, how do I locate the regular filter, Global. Is this a contextual filter, or just a filter under 'filter criteria'?

Comment: In Global, under 'Filter Criteria', I have options for Global: Combine fields filter and Global: Fields comparison

Comment: oops, I think you need the Views PHP module - try that, if it shows up I will edit my answer

Comment: it does require views php - I added that to the answer

Comment: Is this what you meant: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s5/sh/bd1e3916-f105-47ff-a34b-b3ba1ade9986/f1fd063e220ee91e because if yes, then I cannot seem to get it working. I notice that $node is not available to Global:PHP as a variable?

Comment: that appears correct though its nearly impossible to read. $node is assigned in the Global PHP in the first line. how is it not working? does the block not show up? try adding a dumby header that shows even when the view is empty to make sure the block is showing properly. Do you get any errors on screen or in the log when you view the content?